# class instance method takes exactly two args, one given

Tags: python, instance

I am having a bit of an issue. First off, I know that this code is able to stand alone and not be in a class but I would prefer that it is in a class. Second, when I run the code, I get this error `TypeError: set_options() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` .

Here is my code. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. I'm assuming that the set_options method isn't getting my jobj instance. Am I correct in assuming that and how would one go about fixing this? ps. I do have the correct imports and here is my py command at terminal `python test.py radar 127.0.0.1 hashNumber testplan:speed`

```
class TransferStuff(object):
tool = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
hash = sys.argv[3]
options = sys.argv[4]

    def set_options(self, test_options):
        option_arr = test_options.split(',')
        new_arr = [i + ':{}'.format(i) for i in option_arr if ':' not in i]

        for i in option_arr:
            if ':' in i:
                new_arr.append(i)
        d = {}
        for i in new_arr:
            temp = i.split(':')
            d[temp[0]] = temp[1]

        return d

    data = {'target': target, 'test': tool, 'HASH': hash,
            'options': set_options(options)}

    def write_to_json(self):
        """Serialize cli args and tool options in json format.

        Write stream to json file.
        """
        with open('envs.json', 'w') as fi:
            json.dump(TransferStuff.data, fi)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        jobj = TransferStuff()
        jobj.write_to_json()
```

Comment: Please correctly indent your code so it is easier to tell what is part of the class and what is not

Comment: @MoxieBall fixed

Comment: Why do you use a class here at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This isn't my full code. There is another class in this python but it isn't necessary to post it here. Nothing in that class would affect this one. I've made two classes for readability purposes mainly.

Comment: @UCProgrammer your class shares no state between methods, you never use `self`. Anyway, `set_options` takes a `self` parameter, this is why your code is failing when you call it in the `dict` literal: `set_options(options)}`. Why did you think you didn't need to pass it? Anyway, you could pass it anything, since you *never do anything with it*. So `set_options(None, options)` would work, but maybe you should refractor your code not to needlessly use a class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just took it out of the class and left all that code as standalone variables/functions and all works. I know I had to pass self but I was receiving an error when I tried that as well

Comment: @UCProgrammer what were you passing? If you pass an argument to the `self` parameter that would work. Again *anything would do*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was passing self. I believe it has something to do with data not being in any method but rather there as global scope to that class.

Comment: what do you mean you were passing self? There is no `self` in scope there. Again, you can pass it anything, like `None` or `object()` or `'banana'`. Or any variable  in scope. `data` is in the class scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are correct. I was just foolishly putting self in even though I wasn't in any method. putting a string or any other variable in works.  thank you and I apologize for you having to explain that to me. still learning

Answer (score 0):

Your method is inside a class, you need to create a instance of the class:

```
transfer_stuff_instance = TransferStuff()
```

And call the method with this instance:

`transfer_stuff_instance.ser_options(options)`

Comment: I have called the set_options method on the jobj instance and I am receiving the same error.